# Is it possible use a google+ page as author in rich snippet?

Tags: google-plus

is it possible use a google+ page as author in google rich snippet ?
If for example i compare in a google search, the image and name of author of my article is the image and name of may google+ page.

Thanks to all and excuse me for my english

Answer (score 0):

Authorship is meant to be for people so the rel=author links are meant to point to profiles not Pages.